# Testing significance of Strauss parameters in mppm model

Tags: statistics, spatial, anova, spatstat

I have a follow up question from my previous post.

Upon creating mppm models like these:

```
Str <- hyperframe(str=with(simba, Strauss(mean(nndist(Points)))))

fit0 <- mppm(Points ~ group, simba)
fit1 <- mppm(Points ~ group, simba, interaction=Str, 
           iformula = ~str + str:id)
```

Using anova.mppm to run a likelihood ratio test shows that the interaction is highly significant as a whole, but I would also like to test:

1. whether each individual id shows significant regularity.
2. whether some groups of ids show significantly stronger inhibition than other groups, for example, whether ids 1-7 are are significantly more regular than ids 8-10.
3. perform pairwise comparisons of regularity between different ids.

I am aware I could build separate ppm models for each id to test for significant regularity in each id, but I am not sure this is the best approach. Also, I do not think the "summary output" with the p-values for each Strauss interaction parameter can be used for pairwise comparisons other than to the reference level.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me explain that, for Gibbs models, the likelihood is intractable, so `anova.mppm` performs the adjusted composite likelihood ratio test, not the likelihood ratio test. However, you can essentially treat this as if it were the likelihood ratio test based on deviance differences.

> 1. whether each individual id shows significant regularity

> I am aware I could build separate ppm models for each id to test for significant regularity in each id, but I am not sure this is the best approach.

This is appropriate. Use `ppm` to fit a Strauss model to an individual point pattern, and use `anova.ppm` to test whether the Strauss interaction is statistically significant.

> 2. whether some groups of ids show significantly stronger inhibition than other groups, for example, whether ids 1-7 are are significantly more regular than ids 8-10.

Introduce a new categorical variable (factor) `f`, say, that separates the two groups that you want to compare. In your model, add the term `f:str` to the interaction formula; this gives you the alternative hypothesis. The null and alternative models are identical except that the alternative includes the term `f:str` in the interaction formula. Now apply `anova.mppm`. Like all analyses of variance, this performs a two-sided test. For the one-sided test, inspect the sign of the coefficient of `f:str` in the fitted alternative model. If it has the sign that you wanted, report it as significant at the same p-value. Otherwise, report it as non-significant.

> 3. perform pairwise comparisons of regularity between different ids.

This is not yet supported (in theory or in software).

[Congratulations, you have reached the boundary of existing methodology!]

Comment: Thanks so much! Regarding 2, to clarify, is this what you mean  `fit1 <- mppm(Points ~ group, simba, interaction=Str, iformula = ~str + f:str)` ?